# r - Adding time column to data frame based on time count

Tags: r, time, timeline

In my data I have a column of temperature measurements together with a column showing the time passed until the temp was measured by the data logger. 
The dataframe contains 500000+ observations.

```
eggtemp <- read.csv("temp_time.csv", header=FALSE)
colnames(eggtemp) <- c("time passed", "temp")

   time passed   temp      
1  0.00043823    16.876    
2  0.00087645    17.903    
3  0.00131470    18.923    
4  0.00175290    19.933
```

The data logger started recording at 7/30/2014, 13:05:00.

Is there a way to make a new column in the data set, based on the start recording time, showing the exact time at which the measurements were taken?
Like this one (I typed the rough time in by hand for the first 4 rows):

```
   time passed   temp      time
1  0.00043823    16.876    13:05:00:00
2  0.00087645    17.903    13:05:00:04
3  0.00131470    18.923    13:05:00:09
4  0.00175290    19.933    13:05:00:13
```

Can someone tell me if there is a function that takes the starting time and adds the "time passed" values, to get the exact time (and date) of every observation? I just can't figure it out..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the unit of `eggtemp[,'time passed']`, but I'm guessing hours from your typed in values. I use the lubridate package, it makes these calculations easy. Although it's definitely possible with base R.

```
start <- mdy_hms("7/30/2014 13:05:00")
time_passed <- c(0.00043823, 0.00087645, 0.00131470, 0.00175290)
time_passed <- dhours(time_passed)
time <- start + time_passed
```

Make sure to set the tz argument to `mdy_hms` if you're concerned about getting it into a correct local time.

Comment: Worked like a charm for the whole column after changing it to 
"eggtemp$'time passed' <- dhours(eggtemp$'time passed')" and
"time_passed <- eggtemp$'time passed'". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly ways to accomplish this with `strptime` and the like, but I find the `lubridate` package helpful for keeping my head on straight when dealing with time:

```
library(lubridate)

df
#   time_passed   temp
# 1  0.00043823 16.876
# 2  0.00087645 17.903
# 3  0.00131470 18.923
# 4  0.00175290 19.933

options(digits.secs = 3) # to see the milliseconds
start <- ymd_hms("2014-07-30 13:05:00.00")
df$time <- start + milliseconds(df$time_passed * 10000)

df
#   time_passed   temp                    time
# 1  0.00043823 16.876 2014-07-30 13:05:00.004
# 2  0.00087645 17.903 2014-07-30 13:05:00.008
# 3  0.00131470 18.923 2014-07-30 13:05:00.013
# 4  0.00175290 19.933 2014-07-30 13:05:00.017
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Running the code produced an error:
'Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1'

Comment: Okay nevermind, it's working now (changed "df$time_passed" to "df$'time passed' "). Just a syntax error